# How to be sure that Date.today is in Pacific Time Zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, timezone

I am tracking user activity:

```
def track
   UserActivityTracker.new(date: Date.today.to_s).track
end

#application.rb
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

How to be sure that days are tracked in the `Pacific Time (US & Canada)`
 time zone.
I don't want to change time zone in `application.rb`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails will store your data in the db using UTC (which is a good thing)

i don't think changing `config.time_zone` on an existing app is a good idea, the UTC default is probably best

When rails pulls data from the db using ActiveRecord, it will convert datetimes based on the `Time.zone` settings for that request

```
Date.today 
# => server time, rails does not convert this (utc on a typical production server, probably local on dev machine)
Time.zone.now.to_date 
# => rails time, based on current Time.zone settings
```

You can set the current users time zone in a before_filter on ApplicationController, then when you display datetimes use the I18n helpers

```
I18n.localize(user_activity_tracker.date, format: :short)
# => renders the date based on config/locals/en.yml datetime:short, add your own if you wish
# => it automatically offsets from UTC (database) to the current Time.zone set on the rails request
```

If you need to display a time that is not the same as the current `Time.zone` request setting, use `Time.use_zone`

```
# Logged on user is PST timezone, but we show local time for an event in Central
# Time.zone # => PST
<% Time.use_zone('Central Time (US & Canada)') do %>
  <%= I18n.l(event.start_at, format: :time_only_with_zone) %>
<% end %>
```

when saving data, don't bother doing a conversion, let rails save it as UTC, you can display the value in any timezone you wish using the helpers

see also:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-use_zone
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: Hmm, and what if I store date as ``String`` in my database in format: "2012-02-02" is better way than: ``(Date.today.to_time + Time.zone_offset('PST')).to_date.to_s`` because I am storing this in Redis as key name

Comment: a string is a string so I guess that works, makes it difficult to run queries on the data later - a variation on the string code would be `value = Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)') { Time.zone.now.to_date }.to_s`, is that better, not really sure

Comment: Date.current is the Time.zone aware version of Date.today

Comment: awesome, learn something new everyday - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-current

Answer (score 1):

Replace `config.time_zone` this way :

```
config.time_zone = 'PST'
```

If you don't want to change all the dates, you can use `Time.zone_offset`

```
good_date = bad_date + Time.zone_offset('PST')
```

You can add the offset in the initialize or in a before_xxx callback.

Comment: I don't want to set up this generally only for tracking.

Comment: ``Date.today + Time.zone_offset('PST')`` => ``Thu, 17 May 1934``

Comment: ``Date.today.to_time + Time.zone_offset('PST') => 2013-03-22 16:00:00 +0000``